# Do Hyperledger Fabric network need odd no. of orderers if selected raft as ordering

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If selected  OrdererType: etcdraft, then is it must to have odd no. of orderers ?, referred to the following hyperldger fabric documentation but not found anything specific on that?

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/raft_configuration.html

```
Consenters:
            - Host: raft0.example.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert0
              ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert0
            - Host: raft1.example.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert1
              ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric wrote many pages on the documentation about RAFT, but not specifically shared a single example with raft and without a raft, not shared the word: "distributed consensus", saw hundreds of technical articles where the demonstration was done to run X orderers, but when you work on real problems then the real Q comes, how many orderers you may need? (sure all depends on the problem you working on)

Found following reference on this topic :

Reference: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/71083347

> While it's possible to use the console to build a configuration of any
> number of ordering nodes (no configuration is explicitly restricted),
> some numbers provide a better balance between cost and performance
> than others. The reason for this lies in satisfying the needs of high
> availability (HA) and in understanding the Raft concept of the
> "quorum", the minimum number of nodes that must be available (out of
> the total number) for the ordering service to process transactions.
> In Raft, a majority of the total number of nodes is needed to form a
> quorum. In other words, if you have one node, you need that node
> available to have a quorum, because the majority of one is one.
> Similarly, if you have two nodes, you will need both available, since
> the majority of two is two (for this reason, a configuration of two
> nodes is discouraged; there is no advantage to a two node
> configuration). In a similar vein, the majority of three is two, the
> majority of four is three, the majority of five is three, and so on.
> While satisfying the quorum will make sure the ordering service is
> functioning, production networks also have to think about deployment
> configurations that are highly available (in other words,
> configurations in which the loss of a certain number of nodes can be
> tolerated by the system). Typically, this means tolerating two nodes
> failing: one node going down during a normal maintenance cycle, and
> another going down for any other reason (such as a power outage or
> error).   This is why five nodes is a good number for a production
> network. Recall that the majority of five is three. This means that in
> a five node configuration, the loss of two nodes can be tolerated. If
> your configuration features four nodes, only one node can be down for
> any reason before another node going down means a quorum has been lost
> and the ordering service will stop processing transactions.

Also did a few experiments e.g.

- with 1 orderer
- with 2 orderers
  and it worked.

[image: RAFT based orderer]

But even after doing the above, I got an idea that system is working with 1 orderer and 2 orderers or .., but not actually cleared like why we really need 5 to start with.

Possibly start with 1 orderer, and see the complexity of Txns, if we have multiple client applications and those reaching to blockchain network via multiple peers, submitting complex Txn proposals and then it may require 1+X orderers, but yes we have to see what problematic Txns we have. We may not require distributed consensus all time, so not many orderers.

Answer (score 0):

As per latest (Fabric 2.x) [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment_guide_overview.html#step-two-set-up-a-cluster-for-your-resources), it is recommended to deploy at least three and optimally five nodes in an ordering service.

> wherever you choose to deploy your components, you will need to make sure you have enough resources for the components to run effectively. The sizes you need will largely depend on your use case. If you plan to join a single peer to several high volume channels, it will need much more CPU and memory than if you only plan to join to a single channel. As a rough estimate, plan to dedicate approximately three times the resources to a peer as you plan to allocate to a single ordering node (as you will see below, it is recommended to deploy at least three and optimally five nodes in an ordering service). Similarly, you should need approximately a tenth of the resources for a CA as you will for a peer. You will also need to add storage to your cluster (some cloud providers may provide storage) as you cannot configure Persistent Volumes and Persistent Volume Claims without storage being set up with your cloud provider first. The use of persistent storage ensures that data such as MSPs, ledgers, and installed chaincodes are not stored on the container filesystem, preventing them from being destroyed if the containers are destroyed.